# how to add a custom key to Keyboard in ios?

Tags: ios, keyboard

I want to add a custom key to my Keyboard. (a .com key) When user begins to type in email text field this keybord with the key should be appeared. I used keyboard type email. But it not gives that key. How I can add this key to my keyboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is the tutorial that helps you add custom buttons into ios keyboard!

[adding-custom-buttons-to-ios-keyboard](http://easyplace.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/adding-custom-buttons-to-ios-keyboard/)

Answer (score 3):

The .com key is added when the URL type keyboard is used: [KeyboardManagement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

You might as well make use of the inputAccessoryView of the text field, add a UIToolbar to it, and in the toolbar you can add a few buttons you want, including custom .com button.

Answer (score 1):

`There is no way you could change default keyboard`. and If you anyhow modify it(using private methods) apple will reject your app because it is against apple guidelines.

So the only solution to your problem is **create a custom keyboard** and then use it.
There are few custom keyboards you can use them also :

1. [custom-ios-keyboards](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/custom-ios-keyboards)
2. [ioscustomkb](http://thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/63-ioscustomkb.html)
3. [how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-with-custom-navigation-buttons](http://zeroheroblog.com/ios/how-to-create-a-simple-keyboard-with-custom-navigation-buttons)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [custom keyboard](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keyboard)

Integrate one of them into your project and customise it accordingly. Hope it helps to start...

Answer (score 0):

You can't change default keyboard of Apple.

But you can select with keyboard type for `UITextField` or `UITextView` by set some properties in `UITextInputTraits` protocol. With email, set to:

```
[textView setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```

You can use inputAccessoryView to add some custom keys, refer:
[dmforminputaccessoryview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dmforminputaccessoryview)

Last option is create new Keyboard (UIView subclass) and set it to inputView of `UITextView` or `UITextFied`:
[Custom-iOS-Keyboards](https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards)