# Add a button in iPhones default key board

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I had a requirement in my project in which I require a **"Forgot passcode"** kind of button within a numeric iPhone's default key board as in below image.
Can I achieve this without using custom keyboard or third party classes

Can anyone help me to get this?

[image]

Comment: It seems like you need a custom keyboard. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849531/how-to-add-a-custom-key-to-keyboard-in-ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849531/how-to-add-a-custom-key-to-keyboard-in-ios)