# Custom Keyboard on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios-keyboard-extension

I need to create a custom keyboard for my app, but no sure the best way to do it without the user needing to add a keyboard in the settings. If I create a keyboard extension is it possible to set a UITextField's `Keyboard Type` to that custom keyboard? Or will I have to use a UIView to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve, could you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I want to create a custom keyboard, I want a number pad but also some custom buttons on it. The easiest way to do it would be a keyboard extension, but I dont want users to have to go to their keyboard settings and add a new keyboard. I want it to work right out of the box. So I want to know if I can create a keyboard extension, and make that keyboard the default keyboard for text fields in my app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to add a custom key to Keyboard in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849531/how-to-add-a-custom-key-to-keyboard-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a custom keyboard that is specific to a single app, create a view and assign the view to UITextField.inputView:

```
textField.inputView = YourCustomKeyboard()
```

In my search I didn't find a way to tack on additional keys but there are examples of custom keyboards using inputView that are easy to adapt.

[A custom decimal keyboard example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57275689/1816667)

[My hexadecimal keyboard version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886062/1816667)

Comment: is it possible to create that view in an xib file?

Comment: Yes you can. I tried it just to make certain there weren't any hitches.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `accessoryView` to text view for you want to give a few extra buttons.

If you still looking for some more then please go through the below link.
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=keyboard

Comment: Adding a few extra buttons wouldn't be enough, I would want to present a whole view onto the keyboard after a button is pressed